# GIT Исключение содержимого папки .gitignore

Tags: git

Есть папка Images в проекте, в ней много других папок. Мне нужно, чтобы папка Images сохранялась, а содержимое этой папки нет. Что нужно написать в .gitignore для этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать в самой папке `.gitignore` с таким содержанием:

```
# игнорировать всё в этой папке
*
# кроме этого файла
!.gitignore
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую! По такому же принципу можно и любую папку исключить из игнора правильно я понял?

Comment: Да. Сама папка закомиттится в репозиторий, но ее содержимое нет.